# Interrupted release upgrade (14.04 to 15.10) and now system only boots to command line

Tags: boot, command-line, upgrade, xubuntu

I tried to upgrade from Ubuntu 14.04 to 15.10 via `update-manager`.

It all went well, all the packages were downloaded, step "installing packages" (or something like that) was in progress.

I haven't touched my mouse or keyboard, so in a few minutes the screen had blacked, and when I touched the mouse, there was just the blinking underscore at the screen...
I made a wrong decision then to reboot - first by pressing the on/off button - a nice blue xubuntu screen appeared with a rolling progress line, but it seemed to get stuck, so I pressed the button and held it until it shut down...

Then I started my laptop again - and now there's only a command line available.

**Update:** I can `startxfce4`, but it seems to be not the best solution, also networking doesn't work there...

**Update:** `lsb_release` shows the version is already 15.10

Comment: Try logging in (type in username and password) and typing `sudo service lightdm start`.

Comment: GUI login screen appears, I type my password - then the same login screen appears again, I type my password again - and then the same

Comment: Okay, go back to tty1 (`ctrl`+`alt`+`F1`), log in if necessary, then type `sudo service lightdm stop`, then `mv .Xauthority .Xauthority_2016-05-19`.  Then type `sudo service lightdm start` again.

Comment: P.S.:  just personal opinion, but I might recommend updating to 16.04 LTS.

Comment: Totally the same...

Comment: It seems networking is not working to update... How to do that BTW?

Comment: Networking isn't working?  Ok, let's try resetting the permissions on your home folder.  Try this: `sudo chown -R user:user ~`, replacing `user` with your username.

Comment: I have a Swiss keyboard, can't type ~ :( Is it the same as /home/ ? Thank you so much for trying to help, by the way!! Also check my posting updates, pls

Comment: No problem.  I'll probably be off the rest of this evening, but tomorrow I may be able to jot in a few things.  The ~ is `/home/user/` (whatever your username is.

Comment: It's the same after chown-ing...

Comment: Try `dpkg-reconfigure lightdm`.  While you're at it, run `dpkg --configure -a`.  The first command is to reconfigure the lightdm package (login) the second is to reconfigure any packages that were left unconfigured from the update.  I should have thought of this one, earlier, really.  Sorry!

Comment: "lightdm is broken or not fully installed" - after the first command

Comment: Try the second one then the first one.  What now?

Comment: Check my comment to an answer below, please

Comment: @YOY, Do you still struggling with this issue?

Answer (score -1):

You could also reinstall your Ubuntu operating system, keeping your personal files intact:

Boot from an Ubuntu 15.10 live USB drive or DVD. When asked, chose the option to **reinstall**:

[image: Choose reinstall option during installation]

This should keep personal files untouched.

*However, it is always recommended to have an up-to-date backup of all important files - just to be prepared for any accidents!*

Comment: It seems to help, thank you very much, but: 1) wi-fi doesn't work 2) mouse doesn't work 3) display settings are messed up... All three work just fine when booting from a live CD.

Comment: r u saying  even after reinstaling 15.10 from lived cd ----wifi, mouse, display          -settings.....?? are not workingg......

Comment: @YOY: If you have a follow-up question please [open a new question](/questions/ask). The comment section is not the right place for such things. If you want do draw Rubixred's attention to your new question you can put a link to it in a comment to his answer.